# PHP - Como descobrir o elemento menos comum num array

Tags: php, array, sortable

O trabalho consiste em criar 2 arrays com numeros aleatorios entre 0 e 30. Esses 2 arrays devem ser sorteados do elemento mais comum para o menos comum.

De seguida tenho que mostrar para o ecra o elemento mais comum, menos comum e quais os numeros de 0 a 30 faltam nos dois arrays.

Neste momento eu consigo mostrar para o ecra o elemento mais comum, a minha duvida está em saber como descobrir o menos comum.

Já fiz pesquisas sobre as várias funçoes de sort (arsort, asort, krsort, etc) mas mesmo assim nao consegui proceder.

O codigo que tenho é o seguinte:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>
            Totally not a legit website
        </title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <?php
            function veto($min, $max) {

                for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
                    $array1[$i] = rand($min, $max);
                    $array2[$i] = rand($min, $max);
                }

                // print_r($array1);
                // print_r($array2);      

            $count_1 = array_count_values($array1);
            $count_2 = array_count_values($array2);

            arsort($count_1); // sortear 
            arsort($count_2); // descendente

            $first_array1 = key($count_1); //mais repetido do array1
            $first_array2 = key($count_2); //mais repetido do array2

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            $count_first_1 = current($count_1);
            $count_second_1 = next($count_1);   

            if($count_first_1 != $count_second_1) { // para saber se existem repetidos no 1º lugar
                echo $first_array1 . ' mais comum no primeiro array';
                echo "</br>";
            } else {
                echo $first_array1 . ' - input repetido no mais comum';
                echo "</br>"; 
            }          
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            $count_first_2 = current($count_2);
            $count_second_2 = next($count_2);   

            if($count_first_2 != $count_second_2) { // para saber se existem repetidos no 1º lugar
                echo $first_array2 . ' mais comum no segundo array';
                echo "</br>";
            } else {
                echo $first_array2 . ' - input repetido no mais comum';
                echo "</br>";
            }


            print_r ($array1);     
            echo "</br>";
            print_r ($array2);      
            echo "</br>";

            // print_r(end($count_1));
            // echo "</br>";
            // echo print_r(end($count_2));   
            // echo "</br>";


        }

            $min = 0;
            $max = 30;  

            veto($min, $max);
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Só não entendi, o elemento que menos aparece deve comparado em um array ou nos dois? quero dizer vc vai 2 números (1 por array) 'menos frequentes'

Comment: Sim, 2 numeros, 1 por cada array e sim, é comparado cada um no seu array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decidi quebrar a lógica em três partes (funções) a primeira é como montar o array de números selecionados, a segunda a exibição do maior e menor e a última verificar quais números não foram selecionados mas que estão no intervalo informado.

```
function gerarNumeros($min, $max) {
    $arr = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
        $arr[] = rand($min, $max);
    }

    return array_count_values($arr);
}
```

A ideia dessa função é retornar um vetor onde o índice é o número gerado por `rand()` e o valor é quantidade de vezes que ele apareceu quem faz isso é a função `array_count_values()`

A saída é algo como:

```
Array
(
    [13] => 1
    [11] => 3
    [7] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [8] => 1
    [15] => 1
    [6] => 1
    [10] => 1
)
```

---

```
function obterMaiorEMenor($arr){
    $maior = sprintf('O número: %s apareceu %s vezes', array_search(max($arr), $arr, true), max($arr));
    $menor = sprintf('O número: %s apareceu %s vez', array_search(min($arr), $arr, true), min($arr));
    return array('maior' => $maior, 'menor' => $menor);
}
```

A função acima recebe o array gerado e utiliza as funções `max()` e `min()` para obter o maior e o menor valor presente no array. **Detalhe** em caso de quantidades iguais será considerado o maior ou menor o primeiro elemento encontrado.

```
function numerosDeFora($min, $max, $arr){
    return array_diff(range($min, $max), $arr);
}
```

Por último essa função calcula a diferença entre todos os números diponíveis (`range($min, max`) e os selecionados (`$arr`) e retorna um novo array.

Execução do código:

```
$a = gerarNumeros(1, 15);
$extremos = obterMaiorEMenor($a);

$numeros = array_keys($a); //Lembre que os números são os índices e as quantidades os valores
sort($numeros); //classifica do menor para o maior


echo $extremos['maior'] .'<br>'. $extremos['menor'];

echo '<br>Números selecionados: '. implode(', ', array_unique($numeros));
echo '<br>Números de fora: '. implode(', ', numerosDeFora(1, 15, $numeros));
```

Saída:

```
O número: 11 apareceu 3 vezes
O número: 13 apareceu 1 vez
Números selecionados: 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15
Números de fora: 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 12, 14
```

Comment: Compreendi mas fiquei com uma dúvida na funçao obterMaiorEMenor. Na ultima parte em que se define "return array('maior' => $maior, 'menor' => $menor);" há alguma razão especifica para termos de escrever 'maior' => $maior ? Nao poderia mais em baixo simplesmente escrever "echo $extremos[$maior] .'<br>'. $extremos[$menor]; " ? Se a duvida for basica aceitava tbm que me mostrasse onde posso esclarecer (comecei a estudar php na universidade este ano)

Comment: @Xiri_ pode sim, nesse caso foi só para facilitar a formatação.